# Who will qualify for semi-final?

Tags: cricket, icc, tie-breaker

**I wonder which team will qualify if following scenario happen?**

***Here is the scenario:***

> According to group A's point table after Bangladesh defeat New
>   Zealand, if match between Australia and England washout in the rain
>   who will qualify for the semi-final?

Here is the Group A's Point Table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a moot point now as England did beat Australia, but it was a very good question.

According to [Sportskeeda](https://www.sportskeeda.com/cricket/icc-champions-trophy-2017-qualification-scenario-each-team) if points are equal then the team with the most wins will go through before it goes to Run Rate, if that is equal then it goes to team seeding. Therefore Bangladesh would have qualifies as they had won a game whereas Australia had not.

Comment: @ Kevin Anthony Does order matter that mention on the sportskeeda? if that matter than Bangladesh will qualify not Australia

Comment: Please read the link again:
Note:If the points are equal, the team with more wins will go through.If they are still equal, equation goes down to NRR comparison.If still equal, the team with higher seeding goes through

In your example, the points and NRR were equal, therefore the team with the higher seeding would go through, that is Australia, they were seeded ahead of Bangladesh in both the tournament seeding and the world seeding.

Comment: @ Kevin Anthony i got it.

Comment: @Kevin Anthony please note you need to correct your answer because as you quoted here yourself ***"if the points are equal, the team with more wins will go through"*** -- Bangladesh after defeating NZ had 3 points from a win and a no-result in the above table; and if England-Australia match had been washed out, Australia would've had 3 points (same as BD) but no win -- in which case Bangladesh would have qualified ahead of Australia because number of wins is the first tie-breaking rule and net run rate comes only next, for teams with same number of points and same number of wins; seeding last.

Comment: Thank you @EnglishStudent I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Kevin Anthony It's good of you to update your answer, but you should also change the conclusion and say "*if the points are equal, the team with more wins will go through* -- since Bangladesh had a win and Australia had no wins, **Bangladesh would have qualified** ahead of Australia if both teams had finished on 3 points after England-Australia match had been washed out."

Comment: Good point. Updated again.